# Как загрузить *.db файл в sqlite3, если его точное имя заранее не известно?

Tags: php, sqlite3

Проблема следующая: мне необходимо, чтобы подключение происходило к любому найденному sqlite файлу в каталоге, но вот эта конструкция:

```
define('DB_NAME','*.db');
```

не работает. Работает только такая конструкция, т. е. если имя файла известно:

```
define('DB_NAME','dbname.db');
```

Как подсказать скрипту, что подключаться следует к любому файлу с расширением .db?

**Дополнение:**

Вот код, который должен работать с базой:

```
if(file_exists(DB_NAME)) {
    $db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);
} 
else {
    header('Location: install.php');
    exit();
}
```

Здесь, если файл базы не обнаружен, то происходит редирект на скрипт создающий его, имя которого вводится в input (по этому имя не известно заранее, абстрактное).

Comment: Измените заголовок, кратко описав вашу задачу, так как define тут ни при чём - с корректным заголовком вопрос быстрее заметят и вам, возможно, быстрее помогут

Comment: Спасибо Вам за совет :)

Comment: Мда, заголовок стал хуже

Comment: :)) Помогите сформулировать :) Просто, я понимаю, что проблема в синтаксисе, но как правильно указать абстрактное имя файла, не пойму…

Comment: Проблема скорее всего не в синаксисе, а в том, что sqlite3 не умеет и в принципе не должен уметь читать «любой» файл. Нужно писать код, который сам найдёт «любой» файл и передаст его конкретное имя в sqlite3, но лично я не спец по php, может другие пользователи напишут код

Comment: **andreymal** вот спасибо! Очень ёмкий заголовок!

Comment: **andreymal**, т. е. например, функцию поиска в каталоге файла с расширением .db, которая сохранит его имя в переменную, а потом уже в define указать эту переменную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет функция [glob](http://php.net/glob). Найдите подходящие файлы и подключайтесь.

```
$baseDir = __DIR__ . '/db';
$databases = glob($baseDir . '/*.db');

var_dump($databases);
```

Comment: Спасибо :) Выходит, что если файлы находятся в одном каталоге, то будет достаточно `$database = glob('*.db');`? А потом `define('DB_NAME', $database);`?

Comment: Лучше использовать абсолютный путь `__DIR__ . '/*.db'`. Относительный путь относителен от текущей директории, а текущая директория не всегда та, в которой находится скрипт.

Comment: Понятно. А если скрипт в том же каталоге? И вот это синтаксически верно же `define('DB_NAME', $database);`?

Comment: `__DIR__` это и есть каталог, в котором находится скрипт :-) Также обратите внимание, что `glob` возвращает массив, а вам нужен только один его элемент.

Comment: О, как :))) А как его вычленить? Вот так $database[0] ?